objects in gazebo influenced by other objects without contact
I simulated a bouncing ball in gazebo. It was bouncing consistently.
But when I spawn the same ball in an environment with another object (a 4 wheel cart in my case), the ball bounces inconsistently. For example sometimes it bounces more, sometimes less, the distance it covers increases/decreases. To make sure the cart is the issue, i replaced its mesh wheels with cylinder shape. The bounce was more consistent than previous but not perfect(as in the case when there is only the ball in the environment).
I thought the cart is leading to computational load but this might not be true because I am getting constant 62 FPS in gazebo with/without the cart.
100% True points:

The ball and the cart are never in contact.
The force applied to the ball is the same every time.

System:

ROS2 Iron
Gazebo Classic 11

Has anyone had the same situation? Let me know if any other information is required.
